# Update array data based on key in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash, arrayobject

I want to update the data which is array based on key present in another array and if key is not present output the data with value 0 along with corresponding key

```
let data = [{
    ORIGEN: "WB716594",
    "Gestor Ericsson OSS": 1
}, {
    ORIGEN: "MM-LORC-AGUI-L3-11_760525",
    "MM-LORC-AGUI-L3-11_760525": 1
}];

let keyValue = ["Gestor Ericsson OSS",
    "MM-LORC-AGUI-L3-11_760525",
    "Gestor HUA U2KVIA",
    "5620SAM"
]
```

Here "Gestor HUA U2KVIA" and  "5620SAM" is not present in the data and hence it should be append as below

```
Output = [{ORIGEN: "WB716594", Gestor Ericsson OSS: 1, "MM-LORC-AGUI-L3-11_760525":0,Gestor HUA U2KVIA:0,5620SAM:0},
 {ORIGEN: "MM-LORC-AGUI-L3-11_760525", MM-LORC-AGUI-L3-11_760525: 1,Gestor Ericsson OSS: 0,Gestor HUA U2KVIA:0,5620SAM:0}
 ]
```

Comment: Can you properly describe your problem? It is not comprehensible.

Comment: That JSON/Notation Object is not valid. Also what is count data?

Comment: In data array i am not getting all the key, I want to modify based on keyValue, Whichever key is not present i want to update the count to 0 as shown in Output.The first value ORIGEN in the object is groupby value which will be present in all the object in the array

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include a valid [mcve] - No point explaining yourself in the comments

Comment: Hi, this is already provided in description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an object with `keyValue` array items as key and `0` as value. Then loop through the `data` array using `map` and use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to get the merged object for each item:

```js
const data = [{ORIGEN:"WB716594","Gestor Ericsson OSS":1},{ORIGEN:"MM-LORC-AGUI-L3-11_760525","MM-LORC-AGUI-L3-11_760525":1}],
     keyValue = ["Gestor Ericsson OSS","MM-LORC-AGUI-L3-11_760525","Gestor HUA U2KVIA","5620SAM"]

const defaultObj = Object.assign({}, ...keyValue.map(key => ({ [key]: 0 })));
const output = data.map(obj => Object.assign({}, defaultObj, obj));

console.log(output)
```